# Does the Jersey client close the connection on exception?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I've read the [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e4767), and it says Jersey automatically closes a connection after an entity is read (e.g. response.readEntity(SomeObject.class))

But when an exception is thrown, either a bad request or a socket timeout, does Jersey automatically close the connection, or should I have a finally clause that calls client.close()?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Neither does Jersey call `client.close()` in case of an exception nor does the JerseyClient implement [AutoCloseable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html).

You can easily test this. A client throws a IllegalStateException if you invoke a method after closing:

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.close();
client.target("http://stackoverflow.com").request().get(); // IllegalStateException
```

But you can invoke a method after catching an exception:

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
try {
    client.target("http://foo.bar").request().get(); // java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
} catch (Exception ex) {
    client.target("http://stackoverflow.com").request().get(); // works
}
```

So closing is your job.

**Update:** JAX-RS 2.1 [will use AutoClosables](https://java.net/projects/jax-rs-spec/lists/users/archive/2014-10/message/1).

Comment: How about Jersey 1.1x? I checked the API doc and no close() method is found. Only destroy() is available but don't think it's equal.

Comment: From the ApiDoc: "Destroy the client. Any system resources associated with the client will be cleaned up." So connections should be closed.

Comment: One more question, if `Jersey 2.x` with `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` and `ApacheConnectorProvider`, does it need to manually close the client as well?

Comment: Why should it behave different? If you're unsure: My answer provides six lines of code which are testing this. Wouldn't it be an option to simply try it yourself with your setup?

Comment: It's not an option to recreate client on every exception. Is there any other way to close stale connections?